How to expose Salesforce Components in external website (with and without authentication)?
Has anyone worked with the 'Lightning Out' feature in Salesforce, which allows using components outside Salesforce and is currently in Beta? I'm interested in learning about any challenges, limitations, or best practices associated with it. If you have experience with this feature, please share your insights/resources.
Additionally, has anyone used a different approach to expose Salesforce data/component without authentication? If so, what methods have you found effective? Thanks!

Lightning Out requires authentication, and is not compatible with Lightning Web Security. Lightning Out is typically used in Visualforce, although it can technically be used anywhere, as long as you set up authentication.
If you need an unauthenticated method of running your Lightning Web Components, consider using LWR Sites for Experience Cloud. You can set up custom domains to serve your Experience Cloud, or use the default site.com access.
